# Is it possible to become 4x Proficient in a skill?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, feats, multi-classing, ranger

With the ranger’s Deft Explorer trait, you add your proficiency bonus twice in one of your stats that you already have in a stat. If I were to gain expertise in the stat first, and then gain that trait, would I then become essentially 4x proficient (Stat modifier + proficiency bonus + proficiency bonus *2 or Stat modifier + (proficiency bonus + proficiency bonus) * 2)? Would that only be 3x? And, is there any way to double this stat again?

Comment: This looks like D&D 5e, so I’ve added the tag, and this has been asked before, so I’ve pointed it at that question.

Comment: I fixed the question and clarified what i was asking. Thanks for adding the 5e tag, i forgot to do it when i made the question.

Comment: @Celeste: What you were asking, clarified or not, is answered on the other question. The rules are very clear on this, a single multiplier on proficiency bonus is the *limit*, multipliers don't stack in any way.